# Writing a recursive series explicitly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recursion

I am studying a recursive series which looks like this:

$n+\frac{n}{g} + \frac{(n+\frac{n}{g})}{g} + \frac{(n+\frac{n}{g} + \frac{(n+\frac{n}{g})}{g})}{g} + ...$

It is made of the terms in-between the + signs.

The series is recursive because every $n$ in the next term beyond $\frac{n}{g}$ is replaced by $n+\frac{n}{g}$. Since I want to sum these terms up to a certain index, I would need some way of writing them as a summation/sigma. How might I do this?

Comment: Your second term $n/g$ is not obtained from the first term $n$ in this way.

Comment: Do you mean another way then just saying:

Comment: @RobertIsrael -- You're right--I meant every term beyond $n/g$. Thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the first term that doesn't fit the pattern, you seem to be taking $\sum_{k=1}^M T_k(n)$ where $T_{j+1}(n) = T_j(n + n/g)$.
Thus
$$ \eqalign{T_1(n) &= \dfrac{n}{g}\cr
            T_2(n) &= \dfrac{n+n/g}{g} = n \dfrac{g+1}{g^2}\cr
            T_3(n) &= (n + n/g) \dfrac{g+1}{g^2} = n \dfrac{(g+1)^2}{g^3}\cr
            T_4(n) &= (n+n/g) \dfrac{(g+1)^2}{g^3} = n \dfrac{(g+1)^3}{g^4}\cr}$$
and in general 
$$ T_k(n) = n \dfrac{(g+1)^{k-1}}{g^k}$$
 Then
$$ \sum_{k=1}^M T_k(n) = \dfrac{n (g+1)^M}{g^M} - n $$

Comment: Great answer! Could you please explain how you went from the summation to the final answer in your last step?

Comment: It's a geometric series with ratio $(g+1)/g$.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose, as Robert Israel pointed, that you have corrected your mistake and added another $n$ at the beginning of the series to make it coherent with your subsequent sentence.

Call $a_k(m)$ your $k$-th term where you have $m$ at the beginning

$a_0(n) = n$ and $a_{k+1}(n) = a_k(n(1+1/g))$.

Then $a_k(n) = a_{k-1}(n(1+1/g)) = a_{k-2}(n(1+1/g)^2) = \cdots = a_{0}(n(1+1/g)^k) = n(1+1/g)^k$.

So your series is $\sum_{k\geq 0} n(1+1/g)^k$.